# Hi, I need to display data from a table (vw_tracking_resource_events), but only 14 days of data for a certain time (18:00 to 19:00)

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, select, between

I use PostgreSQL

I can run a single query per day, but it will take a long time to go through every day.

The "zone" and "reader" also changes, so to run single queries every time will keep me up until late.
If at best I can only change the "reader" and "zone" every time it would help. The main "PAIN" I have, is to change the dates every time. It will be from 2022 11 18 18:00 to 2022 12 01 19:00.

P.S - I'm new to SQL, please be gentle :)

My current query:

```
select * from vw_tracking_resource_events
where "when_enter_dt_timezone" between '2022 11 18 18:00:00' and '2022 11 18 19:00:00'
and "zone" = '085 Level'
and "site" = 'MK'
and "reader" = 'RV Shaft'
and "group" = 'Lamp'
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone involved. You really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your field to separate and compare the date part and the time part to desired ranges, it becomes super easy:

```
WHERE when_enter_dt_timezone BETWEEN '2022-11-18' AND '2022-12-01T23:59:59.999'
AND when_enter_dt_timezone::time BETWEEN '18:00' AND '19:00'
```

Edit:
@Stefanov.sm makes a very good point regarding the casting of the timestamp to type `date` (1st criterion above) if an index can be used to retrieve data.
I corrected the query to take his remark.

Disclaimer: With `when_enter_dt_timezone::date BETWEEN ... AND 2022-12-01`, you include e.g. `2021-12-01T18:30`.
Without the cast, the upper bound `2022-12-01` is implicitly set to midnight (morning); you will either have to change the upper bound to `2022-12-02` (which @Stefanov.sm suggested and works very well since you have a condition on the time anyway) or set your upper bound to `2022-12-01T23:59:59.999` (which is what I did above, although only to draw your attention to this specific issue).

Comment: I did not mention it in the answer because it is off topic, but you should get rid of the unnecessary double-quotes.

Comment: Casting `when_enter_dt_timezone` as `date` will defeat an index on it (if any). So better `when_enter_dt_timezone BETWEEN '2022-11-18' AND '2022-12-02'`

Comment: Using BETWEEN with timestamp values is always shaky. Better use `when_enter_dt_timezone >= 2022-11-18' and when_enter_dt_timezone < '2022-12-01 19:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to get records for the last 14 days between 6:00 p.m. and 7:00 p.m.

```
select * from vw_tracking_resource_events 
   where when_enter_dt_timezone > current_date - interval '14' day and
when_enter_dt_timezone::time between time '18:00' AND time '19:00'
```

Demo in [sqldaddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/aa1a0975)

Modified using @Atmo notes
and @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: This query returns the record at time 19:39; `between 18 and 19` should be replaced by `= 18`, although a specific condition must then be added to retrieve anything recorded at exactly 19:00:00 (unless the upper bound was to be excluded).

Comment: alternatively: `and when_enter_dt_timezone::time >= time '18:00' and when_enter_dt_timezone::time < time '19:00'`

Comment: I don't think rows that appear precisely at 19:00 should be included therefor the `< time '19:00'`